# Average for each three consecutive numbers in an array

Tags: c

How can I calculate the average for each three consecutive numbers in an array and then to print each result? (in C)

I tried to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n,v[100],i;
  float average;

  int sum=0;
  scanf("%d",&n);

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    scanf("%d",&v[i]);
  }
      
  for(i=0;i<n;i+=3) {
    sum=v[i]+v[i+1]+v[i+3];
    average=sum/3;
    printf("%.2f ", average);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: well what have you attempted?  You need to show some effort

Comment: If you have, say, 6 elements, their indices will be 0,1,2,3,4,5.  You want to take the average of (0,1,2), and (1,2,3), and (2,3,4), and (3,4,5).  But your loop `for(i=0; i<n; i+=3)` is going to hit just (0,1,2) and (3,4,5), due to the `+= 3`.

Comment: @OldProgrammer As OP provided code, you may want to re-visit the post.

Answer (score 1):

`sum/3` is an `int` division with an `int` quotient.

To also have a fractional part, use floating point division.

```
// average=sum/3;
average = sum / 3.0f;
```

---

`for(i=0;i<n;i+=3) { sum=v[i]+v[i+1]+v[i+3];` risks accessing data out of `v[]` bounds.  `v[i]+v[i+1]+v[i+3]` are not consecutive.  I'd expect `v[i]+v[i+1]+v[i+2]`

```
for (i = 0; i + 2 < n; i += 3) {
  sum = v[i] + v[i+1] + v[i+2];
```

---

No good reason to use `float`.  Use `double` unless `float` is needed for space/ maybe speed, etc.

Also avoid overflow and precision loss.

```
for(int i = 0; i+2 < n; i += 3) {
  double sum = 0.0 + v[i] + v[i+1] + v[i+2]; // Addition here uses FP math.
  double average = sum/3.0;
  printf("%.2f ", average);
}
```

---

Better code writes a `'\n'` at the end and does not end with a dangling `" "`.

```
const char *separator = "";
for(int i = 0; i+2 < n; i += 3) {
  ...
  printf("%s%.2f ", separator, average);
  separator = " ";
}
printf("\n");
```